# Help needed in drawing 3D scrollbars

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I need to write the following component in WPF:

[image]

It should be over image, I should able to drag the lines with the mouse (drag X up and down, drag Y left and right, and Z spin from horizontal to vertical)

My backround in WPF is almost not exist,

Can you give me guidliness? do you know component that doing it, or something similar to that?
Do you know what is the name of this control?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it,

[You can download the code here](http://uploading.com/files/md8e6971/lines.rar)

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the program in 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part1.aspx

In the code I just remark 
//Canvas.SetTop(designerItem, top + e.VerticalChange);
And remain 
Canvas.SetLeft(designerItem, left + e.HorizontalChange);

Delete almost everything, replaced image with rectangle,

And now the verical and horizontal lines drag and drop lines work,

Now I am searching how to do the diagonal line drag and drop
(I tried to do it with path/line control, I had the problem that if I add the diagonal line, it capture all the mouse event, and I can't move the other lines)

Help still needed