# WPF diagonal line drag and drop

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, line, rotation

How can I write in WPF diagonal line with drap and drop behavior?

I need to move it to the left and right,
And if drag it from the top or bottom than to rotate it.

[My original post can be found under this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460020/help-needed-in-drawing-3d-scrollbars)

-----------------Edit-------------------------------------------------------

I am able to draw diagonal line with drag and drop, my problem is the mouse event area for his drag and drop is a whole square and not only the line, so basically now I can move the line without the mouse to be over the line, this causes another problem, that I can't move other controls inside this square range.

-----------------Second Edit------------------------------------------------

Now I was able to rotate I just used

```
<Rectangle Fill="Blue" IsHitTestVisible="False" x:Name="m_Rect">
  <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
     <TransformGroup>     
          <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
     </TransformGroup>
   </Rectangle.RenderTransform>            
 </Rectangle>
```

And that helped me to creat the diagonal line with drag and drop behavior
Now my problem is that inside the event in c# the rectangle is out of scope..

Comment: I know how to implement the drag-and-drop begavior, but the rotation isn't easy task for me.

Comment: You can use the `Line` control, it handles mouse events correctly. But it isn't easy to rotate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it,

[You can download the code here](http://uploading.com/files/md8e6971/lines.rar)